# Heroku deploy button fails when specifying standard-0 tier in Postgres add-on in app.json

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-api

I'm trying to create a [Deploy to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button) button and have created an `app.json` file in my GitHub repository.

I want to include an add-on for Postgres and specify the [`standard-0`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans#standard-tier) tier. This is what I've added in `app.json`:

```
"addons": [
  {
    "plan": "heroku-postgresql:standard-0"
  }
]
```

Clicking on the deploy button takes you to the appropriate **Create New App** page in Heroku, but it will fail to deploy with the following error message (see screenshot below).

However, it works just fine when I use the `hobby-dev` tier instead.

```
"addons": [
  {
    "plan": "heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev"
  }
]
```

I am wondering if there's another way to specify a paid tier or if there's something that I'm not doing right.

---

#### References

- [Creating a 'Deploy to Heroku' Button](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button)
- [`app.json` Schema](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#addons)
- [Setting Up Apps Using the Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-up-apps-using-the-heroku-platform-api#add-ons)

#### Screenshot of error message

[image]

Comment: Do you have billing information set up for this account? You can't add paid addons without a credit card on file.

Comment: Yes, I have a credit card on file.